# reading a txt file line by line using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm being able to print the entire file contents using:

```
write(document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML);
```

But how do I retrieve and print file contents line by line?

Comment: File handling is never possible in JS , you need to be specific while asking question..

Comment: I believe anything is possible, including file handling in JS...and I've solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **split** function and the delimiter "\r\n" or "\n" to extract all the individual lines in your loaded content, and then perform whatever you wish to do with them:

```
var text = document.getElementById('iframe').contentDocument.body.firstChild.innerHTML;
var lines = text.split("\n");            // this will extract all the lines
for (i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {         // this will move over all the lines
    var current_line = lines[i];         // this contains every line at its turn
    // do here what ever you want to do with current_line
}
```